# Google Tag Manager is only working on specific version of IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, internet-explorer-11, google-tag-manager

We put a function from the GTM `dataLayer.push()` to our web application written in ASP.NET to get specific data when user trigger the send button in the form. Everything works fine. GTM always detected events and values from users using Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE11 (ver. 11.615.xxx). The main problem is that when we try to send form from the Internet Explorer 11 (different ver. than 11.615.xxx, older), it doesnt detect active user or even events with values. Is that a problem with versions of IE11 or something else?

Comment: (disclaimer I don't know google analytics) Could you explain the problem in more detail?  ATM I'm not sure if there is enough information to resolve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Check if there is any error or warning message in console of IE. You said that it is working in IE11(ver.11.615.x) but not working in older version, so both machines are in same network? If not, is there any difference in their configuration or settings? If yes, than try to make similar setting and make a test. If it is working with newer version than it is advisable to use the latest version of IE. If above steps not helps to solve the issue than kindly try to provide any sample code with detailed steps to test the issue. Also ask here  https://support.google.com/tagmanager/community?hl=en

Comment: The machines are in the same network. I compared all setttings, plugins and registry files. nonthing suspicious.

Comment: For testing purpose, try to update IE with the same version which is working on other machine to check whether it starts work or not may help to narrow down the issue.